# Mongoose connection config fail

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nodemon

When I run the following command, sudo nodemon, I've got the following errors.

Any idea about I could fix them.

[nodemon] 1.12.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
/Users/raulvilloravalencia/Documents/bitbloq-backend/app/app.js:16
mongoose.connect(config.mongo.uri, config.mongo.options);
                             ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'uri' of undefined
    at Object. (/Users/raulvilloravalencia/Documents/bitbloq-backend/app/app.js:16:30)
    at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:568:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object. (/Users/raulvilloravalencia/Documents/bitbloq-backend/index.js:7:28)
    at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:665:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:607:3
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Comment: Seems _config.mongo_ is undefined. Could you show your config object ?

Comment: I didn't know I should have one. Could you me some example about how to build one? Thank you so much by the way.

Comment: Take a look at the very good _Mongoose_ [connections](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html) documentation.